# Ansible - change the register output / out

Tags: ansible, output, stdout

I have the following code:

```yaml
    - name: select
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
    
      vars:
        dict1: [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 5, "b": 5, "c": 6},{"a": 8, "b": 9, "c": 10}]
    
      tasks: 
    
      - debug:
          var: dict1 | selectattr('a','ne',1) | selectattr('b','ne',5)
        register: output
    
      - debug:
          msg: "{{output}}"
```

Which gives this result

> ok: [localhost] => {
> "msg": {
> "changed": false,
> "dict1 | selectattr('a','ne',1) | selectattr('b','ne',5)": [
> {
> "a": 8,
> "b": 9,
> "c": 10
> }
> ],
> "failed": false
> }

I need to send this result through an email but I don't want recepiant to see:

> "changed": false, "dict1 | selectattr('a','ne',1) |
> selectattr('b','ne',5)":

and

> "failed": false

He should see only this:

> ```
>         {
>             "a": 8,
>             "b": 9,
>             "c": 10
>         }
> ```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable

```yaml
    dict2: "{{ dict1|selectattr('a', 'ne', 1)|
                     selectattr('b', 'ne', 5)|
                     first }}"
```

and format it as you like. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict2|to_nice_json }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    {
        "a": 8,
        "b": 9,
        "c": 10
    }
```